# Cardinality of subsets of real numbers

Tags: analysis, functions

Let A $\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ \ A have the same cardinality.

Use We proved that if X is infinite and B = {x1} $\subseteq$ X then Y := X\B is infinite
and there is a bijection f : X $\to$ Y . Thus removing one element from an infinite set does
not change its "size". In a similar way, it is possible to select a countable subset B $\subseteq$ X, set
Y := X \ B and yet construct a bijection f : X$\to$ Y . To do so, select a countable subset
A := {x1, x2,... xn, ..} of X.

Then let

B :={x $_2$$_k$$_-$$_1$|k $\epsilon \mathbb{N^+}$}, set Y := X \B and define f : X $\to$ Y by
f(x$_n$) = x$_2$$_n$ for x$_n$ $\epsilon$ A
and
f(x) = x for x $\epsilon$ X\A.

Then f is a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First $\mathbb{R} /\ A \subset \mathbb{R} \implies |\mathbb{R} /\ A| \leq |\mathbb{R}|$.
If you assume $ |\mathbb{R} /\ A| < |\mathbb{R}|$, then:
$$|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R} /\ A|+|A| < |\mathbb{R}|+|A|=|\mathbb{R}|$$
So $|\mathbb{R} /\ A|=|\mathbb{R}|$ must hold.